# Get the most frequent value in a linking table and refer back to it in a main table in MySQL

Tags: mysql, join, count

I have a couple of tables being used in a Star Wars database along with a joining table (this is part of a Uni project).

I'm trying to write a query where it will return what the most common mode of transportation is, based on the characters in a table, and modes of transportation in another table linked together by a joining table.

The primary key in both the person and transportation tables is a simple "id" column, and then both tables have a name column.

A linking table called person_transportation has been created with columns containing the ids from both the person and transportation tables.

I can run the following query:

```
SELECT transport_id 
FROM person_transport 
GROUP BY transport_id 
ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
DESC LIMIT 1
```

And that returns the value 2 (which is the correct ID for the ship I want).  I can't seem to find a way to put this query into another query which will return the ship name instead of an ID number.

I have searched through plenty of similar issues in here, but they all seem to relate to a query being run on a single table, not a linking table.

Any ideas?

Comment: Provlde DDL and sample data for both tables and desired result for this data.

Comment: Please [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query) see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess there is a `transport_table` with columns like `transport_id` and `transport_name`.
Use your query in a `WHERE` clause like this:

```
SELECT transport_name
FROM transport_table
WHERE transport_id = (
  SELECT transport_id 
  FROM person_transport 
  GROUP BY transport_id 
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) 
  DESC LIMIT 1
)
```

Change the table's name and the column names to the actual names.

Comment: Fantastic.  That fixed it.  I had something similar, but some of my contexts were wrong, and it kept failing.  Thank you very much!